# Checking for specific permissions of Oracle users

Tags: oracle, join

**Problem:** I am working on a query that will produce a list of all Oracle users.  I wish to determine in the query if they have the specific grant permissions for `CONNECT` and `APPUSER` and show them in a single table.

**What I have tried:** I am using *one* table, `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS`.  This table shows all the information I need, but am failing to query it correctly.  I can show all users who have permission to `Connect` with:

```
SELECT GRANTEE as "User Name", granted_role as "Connect"
FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
WHERE GRANTED_ROLE='CONNECT';
```

I can also show users who have permission to `APPUSER`, simply by replacing `CONNECT` with `APPUSER`.

My problem is showing both permissions in one query.  I have tried using different `JOIN`s.  However, using that seems to require two tables or more.  I have researched a "self-join", but do not understand how to use two `WHERE` clauses. I have tried things like:

```
SELECT grantee as "User Name", t1.granted_role as "Connect", t2.granted_role as "APPUSER" 
FROM t1.DBA_ROLE_PRIVS join t2.DBA_ROLE_PRIVS on t1.GRANTEE = t2.GRANTEE 
WHERE t1.GRANTED_ROLE='CONNECT' and t2.GRANTED_ROLE='APP_USER';
```

I want my final query to show something like:

```
User Name         Connect        App User
----------       ----------     ---------- 
 Bob              CONNECT        APPUSER
 Sue                             APPUSER
 Nick             CONNECT        APPUSER
 Rob              CONNECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GRANTEE as "User Name", granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE in ('CONNECT','APPUSER');
```

if you need one row for each user and two column for each access, you can use this

```
select  c.GRANTEE as "User Name", a.granted_role as "Connect", c.granted_role as "APPUSER" 
FROM
(SELECT GRANTEE, granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE = 'CONNECT')  a,
```

FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT GRANTEE, granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE = 'APPUSER') c
    on a.GRANTEE  = c.GRANTEE;

Comment: This does combine my two queries, which I thank you for.  However, it still will list `Bob` and `Nick` twice and only have two columns.  I am really trying to find a way that has three rows.  First the user name, then if they have `Connect` rights, last if they have `App User` rights.

Comment: updated the answer as per you need. I have wrote it on notepad check for any syntax typo, it should work

Comment: I have updated your answer to something I that produces an answser correctly.  It seems to only show users who have both `CONNECT` and `APPUSER` rights.  It does not show users with only one right.  Thank you @Panther

Comment: Thanks kyle, it should be fullyout join

Comment: added full outer join. check if any syntax correction needed